# Django QuerySet Strange Behavior: Same object returned for First and Last element

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

This is my model:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    filmmaker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In my view a user can select a film from a dropdown and go over the details of that film.

My View:

```
@login_required()
def home(request):

    movies = Film.objects.filter(filmmaker=request.user)

    # I added the following to debug. Assume there are 4 elements in the queryset
    print movies[0].title, movies[3].title
    print movies[1].title, movies[2].title

    ...
```

The console output is such and WRONG:

```
title1 title1
title2 title3
```

However when I run manage.py shell and create the queryset manually,

```
>>> movies = Film.objects.filter(filmmaker__email='email@email.com')
>>> print movies[0].title, movies[3].title
>>> print movies[1].title, movies[2].title
```

The output is as expected:

```
title1 title4
title2 title3
```

What is happening here? Where am I going wrong? What can I do to fix it? Can't seem to be able to understand this strange behavior

Comment: Who is the filmmaker for `movies[3]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can help you much without seeing the overall database structure and data.

but one thing to note is that in the first instance you query based on request object, and the second you query based on email address.

Maybe before querying, try to elaborate request.user object first, and see whether name/email/etc is what you are expecting.